# Stop SmtpClient from converting link (text) to href

Tags: c#, email, hyperlink, smtpclient

We use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient to send out emails. Some of our emails contain links, but we do not want them to be rendered as clickable when we send them.
The SmtpClient and MailMessage is set up using the following:

```
using var smtp = new SmtpClient(_emailSettings.SmtpHost, _emailSettings.SmtpPort))
{
   var mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(sender), new MailAddress(recipient))
   {
       Subject = email.Subject,
       Body = email.Body,
       IsBodyHtml = true
   };
   await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

An example email body could be:

> Example text with link: www.test.no

But when we send out the email, the raw text of the links gets converted into `<a href="www.test.no">www.test.no</a>` by the smtp client, and the link is rendered as clickable.
From debugging the solution, we have made sure that the body is text only without any anchor tags before the `smtp.SendMailAsync(mail)` function call.

We can circumvent the problem by injecting "invisible" spaces into the link, so that it is not recognised as a clickable link:

> Example text with link: www&#823.test.no

However, we wonder whether or not it is possible to set up the SmtpClient to not convert the links to `<a href... >` in the first place?

Comment: As you said yourself, its the mail client that renders the link as clickable. If you cannot edit the settings of the client I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change IsBodyHtml from true to false
IsBodyHtml = false;